# VS 2008 VB net Include local file in publish

Tags: vb.net

First of all sorry for my English.

I am new in 2008 and i have a very simple question.

I have made a program in vb net that load one ini file and make some things.
It is possible to include this ini file when i make publish my program?
I want this ini file to copied when i make a setup my program

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Right-Click on your .ini file in Solution Explorer. Select Properties.

In Properties, Select "Copy to Output directory" and change it to 'Copy Always' (or 'Copy if Newer' if you prefer)

Answer (score 1):

if you right click the file in the solution explorer,select properties, and set Copy to Output Directory to either copy option and set the Build Action to Content.

Comment: You might want to mention that it has to be added first.